# What is sudo chown -R $USER:www-data [path]?

Tags: users, ownership

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data [path]
```

Why is there a colon and a `username` after `$USER`?

I mean, if we recursively make our current `$USER` as the owner, why do we need the colon and the `www-data username` afterwards?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man chown`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
```

Essentially, you're recursively (`-R`) setting the owner (`$USER`) and the owning group (`www-data`) on every file and folder within your directory (`/some/path`).

The colon separates the owner value from the group value.

Answer (score 0):

It's enables you to own and therefore have permissions over the files under `/some_path`.

Also note that many applications require that you($USER) own the files, or else you may encounter permission issues when trying to open or modify files under that folder.

The colon separates the [user and the group](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/user-management.html) which own `some_path`. A group may have multiple users including yourself. To answer your second question, Apache has a username and a group called `www-data`. So by having `www-data` own the directory, Apache will have certain permissions(recursively) over that directory.